# Вывести картинку ACF категории

Tags: php, wordpress

Я сделал через ACF возможность вывести картинку категории

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но картинка почему-то не выводится. Почему так может быть?

```
  <?php $cats = get_terms([
                                       'taxonomy' => 'category',
                                       'hide_empty' => true,
                                     ] );

                     
                     if($cats) : ?>
                        <div class="sidebar-widget archives">
                            <div class="widget-inner">
                                <div class="sidebar-title">
                                    <h4><?php pll_e('CATEGORIES'); ?></h4>
                                </div>

                                <div class="outer clearfix">     
                                <?php foreach ($cats as $item) :?>                               
                                    <div class="archive-block">
                                        <div class="inner">
                                            <div class="image">
                                                <img src="<?php the_field('cat_image', 'reviews_' . '77');?>" alt="">
                                                <div class="count"><?php echo $item->count?></div>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="post-title"><a href="/category/<?php echo $item->slug?>"><?php echo $item->name?></a></div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                 <?php endforeach;?>    
                                </div>
                                
                            </div>
                        </div>
                         <?php endif;?>
```

Comment: Откуда здесь `the_field('cat_image', 'reviews_' . '77');` берется `reviews`? Замените на `term` или название таксономии (в данном случае это category). + наверное так как это цикл, то для каждой категории Вам захочется вывести свою картинку, верно? Почему в таком случае там захардкожено 77, а не подставляется `term_id`?

Comment: Это я пытался картинку хотя бы одной категории вывести, но не получилось) 
Я и без reviews и 77 пробовал, не получается)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот что мне помогло

```
 <img src="<?php the_field('cat_image','category_' . $item->term_id);?>" alt="">
```

category_ - так и нужно писать, если вы хотите вывести картинку категории.

`$item->term_id` - из цикла подтягивается id той самой категории